# What's the exact meaning of "will be held"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I frequently read

> "This meeting will be held next Wednesday..."

and sentenctes like that. I understand it means "this will take place", but I am curious about the exact meaning of "be held".

- When is it used?
- Is it used just in formal texts? Is it also used in normal conversations?

Comment: Try looking up [hold](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hold) in the dictionary (sense 8). “Will be held” is simply the future passive (we will hold the meeting -> the meeting will be held by us).

Comment: Thanks, @JanusBahsJacquet . As it solves my question, you can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking up [hold](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hold) in the dictionary (sense 8). “Will be held” is simply the future passive (we will hold the meeting -> the meeting will be held by us).

Answer (score 1):

When we think of the word *held*, we tend to think about literal/actual arms or hands holding something.

> "I held her in my arms as she wept."

How the word *held* (and hold) came to have a figurative, non-literal meaning is unclear to me.  The word is, however, used idiomatically to mean roughly "to take place or to occur."

In a sentence, the word can be used either formally or informally.

Some other idiomatic uses for the word would include, for example,

> "Hold on there, friend, it's not yet nine o'clock,"

meaning, "Be patient, my friend . . .."

Or,

> "Hold your breath and count to ten,"

meaning, "Don't let the air escape from your lungs."  In other words, let your lungs "hold onto" the air.

> "My job application was put on hold until the first of the year,"

meaning, "My job application would not be considered until January."  In other words, the company would "hold" your application but would not do anything with it until January.

> "The criminal held up the bank,"

meaning the criminal robbed the bank.  (Don't ask me how *robbed* and *held up* came to mean the same thing!)

> "There was a hold-up with their delivery of the package,"

meaning, "There was a delay with their delivery."  If the people delivering the package are holding it, literally, it can't be delivered, yes?  It's delivered only when they release the package from their hands, thereby giving it to you.

> "He held onto the impractical idea until the day of his death,"

meaning, "He kept or stored the impractical idea in his mind until he died."

There are probably many more idiomatic uses for *hold* and *held*, but I think you get my point.  English is, indeed, a funny language!  So many idioms, and so little time.

Comment: It is very common for words meaning ‘hold/grasp/catch/etc.’ to develop wider meanings. Indeed, the verb ‘to have’ in English is etymologically the same as the verb _capiō_ ‘grab/grasp’ in Latin, where Latin has preserved the original, more restricted meaning of the word.

Comment: Good point.  My favorite idiom is "I see," meaning "I understand."  The metaphorical underpinnings of many (if not most) of our idioms is a source of many misunderstandings and much confusion for learners of English.  Perhaps all languages have their share of "hard-to-grasp(!)" ideas.

Comment: This is about four years late, but I just saw this now. It may interest you to know, if you did not already, that _see_ itself originally meant ‘follow’ (whence ‘follow in the mind/with the eyes’ > ‘perceive’ > ‘see’): its Proto-Germanic ancestor _*sehwan-_ is quite transparently cognate with Latin _sequor_ ‘I follow’ (as in _sequence_ and _non sequitur_).